# How to update color of one specific menu item in Elementor main nav menu?

Tags: css, elementor

I would like to update the last menu option titled "Rezerwacja Online" in the main navigation menu of my site ([psycholog-online.co.uk] (https://psycholog-online.co.uk)). The site is built on Elementor. I can see the custom css code I added when I inspect in developer tools, but it is being overwritten by some global css and I don't know how to make my new custom code have a higher priority.

Can anyone help show me how to make this custom code load last so that it overwrites any previously applied css?

Steps I have taken to try and achieve this:

1. Updated 'screen options' in Appearance > Menus to enable Css Classes
2. Added a custom CSS class to the one menu option i'd like to change the color of
3. Added the following custom CSS to the main menu:

```
.rezerwacja.menu-item > a {color: #D76C35} !important;
```

It seems to be getting overwritten by the following:

```
.elementor-365 .elementor-element.elementor-element-272b066 .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item {
    color: #7a7a7a;
    fill: #7a7a7a;
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in CSS it’s not just about the sequence of your rules, it’s about their [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as well. In fact, specificity is the more important of the two. A more specific rule will always override a less specific rule. If two rules have the same specificity, then a later rule will override an earlier one.

As you said, the color of your top menu is coming from this rule:

```
.elementor-365 .elementor-element.elementor-element-272b066
.elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}
```

To change the color of the last menu item (to blue, for example) we need a way to target that item. You’ll see in the generated code that each `<li>` in the navigation menu has a unique classname: for the last item in the menu that classname is `menu-item-1165`. We can use that classname to target this one specific menu item. (You could also use the `rezerwacja` custom class you added to this menu item.) However, as you have found, a simple rule like this doesn’t have any effect:

```
.menu-item-1165 a {
  color: blue;
}
```

The reason this rule has no effect is that it is **less specific** than the rule which applies `color: #7a7a7a;`. This rule has one class selector and one type selector, whereas the other rule has five class selectors. You can read more about how specificity calculations work at the link in the first paragraph above.

So when creating a rule to change the color of your last menu item to blue, you need to start with the most specific rule which exists already, and make it even more specific. As you can see here, I have taken the earlier rule and added the selector `.menu-item-1165` into the correct place in the list of selectors, making this overall declaration **more specific** than the other one.

```
.elementor-365 .elementor-element.elementor-element-272b066
.elementor-nav-menu--main .menu-item-1165 .elementor-item {
    color: blue;
}
```

I think you’ll find that if you add this rule to your styles (anywhere you can), it will override the other rule and turn your menu item blue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of this, but makes complete sense now you explain it.